# Tomcat 500 Internal Server Error while application is still querying database

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, cloudera

I'm developing an API in java, running on a Tomcat server, that queries a database.

Sometimes, when queries take longer, the server throws a 500 Internal Server Error after exactly 60 seconds since the request was made, i.e., since the API was called. I can see, on Cloudera Manager, that the query is still running, though.

If the query ends in less than 60 seconds, results are shown.  I'm using Spring-MVC on the web app. How can I make the server wait for the app response?

Comment: and the question is??

Comment: @M.Deinum Basically, how can I make the server wait longer for an app response?

Comment: @João there is an attribute in server.xml that controls this.  I posted an answer.  Please implement my answer and if it works upvote/accept.  Also in the future please post the tomcat version you're running

Comment: Can you provide a (possibly simplified) version of the called method? Is it an asynchronous method?

Answer (score 0):

## connectionTimeout Attribute

In server.xml there is a `<connector>` element with a variety of optional and required attributes. If the connectionTimeout attribute is not supplied it will default to 60 seconds. You can try to set `connectionTimeout=300000` to increase the server timeout to 5 minutes.  Value is specified in milliseconds so update accordingly.

Here is a [reference document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)

[image]

> Keep in mind that the client can timeout as well.  So make sure the timeout set on the client request is greater than or equal to the value set by the server via connectionTimeout